# Facet barplot isn't respecting colorvalues

Tags: r, bar-chart

I want a faceted barplot. The bars indicating a total value have to be red, the others blue.
A total value is indicated by Desc1="-  ". 
I have the following code:

```
#df contains the following data:                                                                                                        
#Year;Maingroup;Desc1 ;Desc2      ;Value
#2017;A               ;1        ;A1             ;10
#2017;A               ;2        ;A2             ;20
#2017;A               ;-        ;AT             ;30
#2017;B               ;10       ;B10            ;100
#2017;B               ;20       ;B20            ;200
#2017;B               ;-        ;BT             ;300                                                                                                    
#2017;C               ;11       ;C100           ;53
#2017;C               ;22       ;C200           ;54
#2017;C               ;-        ;CT             ;107

#add a new description                                                                                                                  
df <- df %>% unite (Oms,Desc1,Value,sep=' ',remove=FALSE)
#add color indication
df <- df %>% mutate(colv=(ifelse(Desc1=="-      ","Red","Blue")))
#sort into descending order
df <- df %>% arrange(desc(Value))
#plot horizontal barchart
ggplot(df, aes(x=Desc2,y=Value))+
geom_bar(position=position_dodge(),stat="identity",fill=df$colv)+
facet_grid(~Maingroup,scale="free")+
coord_flip()
```

But R isn't coloring the bars in the right way. 
[image: Wrong bar colors]
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess you need to put the `fill = ...` inside an `aes()` call

Comment: Thanks for the superquick response,tried that, but that didn't work

Comment: Then I suggest you post a minimal example of your actual data (after processing) using `dput` so we can try and see what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use fill=colv inside aes() at the begining, and then use scale_fill_manual() for defining the colors like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Desc2,y=Value, fill=colv))+
geom_bar(position=position_dodge(),stat="identity") +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) +
facet_grid(~Maingroup,scale="free") +
coord_flip()
```